# How to use Objective-C CocoaPods in a Swift Project

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoapods

Is there a way I can use a CocoaPod written in Objective-C in my Swift project using swift?

Do I just make a bridging header? And if so, can I access the objects, classes, and fields defined by the libraries in the CocoaPod in Swift?

Answer (score 175, accepted):

Basic answer to your question is Yes, you can use objective-c code built with CocoaPods.

More important question is "How to use such libs?"
Answer on this question depends on `use_frameworks!` flag in your `Podfile`:
Let's imagine that you want use Objective-C pod with name `CoolObjectiveCLib`.

**If your pod file uses `use_frameworks!` flag:**

```
// Podfile
use_frameworks!
pod 'CoolObjectiveCLib'
```

Then you don't need add any bridge header files.
Everything that you need is import framework in Swift source file:

```
// MyClass.swift
import CoolObjectiveCLib
```

Now you can use all classes that are presented in lib.

**If your pod file doesn't use `use_frameworks!` flag:**

```
// Podfile
pod 'CoolObjectiveCLib'
```

Then you need create bridging header file and import there all necessary Objective-C headers:

```
// MyApp-Bridging-Header
#import "CoolObjectiveCLib.h"
```

Now you can use all classes that are defined in imported headers.

Comment: how to access swift classes from inside pod .m files (in case i want  to customise these pods) ?

Comment: I had use_frameworks uncommented in my swift project's podfile and wanted to use the Toast pod, which actually is an objective-c category. By simply writing import UIView+Toast gave me compilation error: Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'

Comment: @ChanchalRaj is `UIView+Toast` name for your pod? If not try to use import framework which name matches to your pod name.

Comment: @Visput The name of the pod is Toast, tried it too, but didn't work. Here is the github link: https://github.com/scalessec/Toast

Comment: @ChanchalRaj Just tried and it works fine. Steps I did: 1. Add `pod 'Toast'` to my pod file. 2. Updated pods. 3. Add `import Toast` to swift file where I want to use this lib. 4. Create view `let view = UIView()`. 5. Call lib method: `view.makeToast("My message")`

Comment: @Visput, thanks for trying. Did u create a swift project? As mentioned by me earlier I had a swift project and wanted to use this objective-c pod.

Comment: @ChanchalRaj, I used existing swift project, and I tried it with exactly that pod that you referenced. Just try my steps, probably you missed something.

Comment: @AbhishekThapliyal What exactly doesn't work? Or what error do you see?

Comment: I have used same code to use objc code to swift file but it gives me error no such a module "POD NAME" , Do I need to set any other flag

Comment: @MikeAlter Could you show how your pod file looks like?

Comment: @VladPapko I found the solution , I am using static library  so it was not working , so I found solution that I have to use Umbrella bridging

Comment: If you are facing issues with **use_frameworks!**, it might be because the import statements are not written in the correct format. e.g. if the podFile contains `pod 'iOS-Echarts'`, then imports shall happen like following:

_Swift file_: `import iOS_Echarts`

_Objective-C file_: `#import <iOS_Echarts/iOS-Echarts.h>`

Comment: For me your answer clear all confusions.. Thanks Man

Comment: These steps do not work if you are working in a CocoaTouch framework :'(

Answer (score 3):

In podFile use the flag `use_frameworks`!
Inside Xcode in the `Pod` folder structure in the dependency, you   add `xxxxxxx-umbrella.h` in Support Files.

In your `{PROJECT_NAME}-Bridging-Header.h` use:

```
#import "xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx-umbrella.h"
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a bridging header and import there what you need.

Answer (score 0):

AND don't forget to add Bridging Header file name to Target -> Build Settings -> Objective-C Bridging Header