# How to use FCUUID in a Swift project?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

[FCUUID](https://github.com/fabiocaccamo/FCUUID) is a Objective-C pods and I want to integrate it in my Swift projects.

My podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'ME' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for ME
  pod 'PayPal-iOS-SDK'
  pod 'FCUUID'
end
```

Then I tried those ways to import FCUUID module:

1. Direct use `let a = FCUUID()`
2. Add a bridge header and `#import "FCUUID.h"` ('FCUUID.h' file not found)

But it all failed.

So what is the correct way to import FCUUID into a Swift project?

PS:

I have tried all methond from [How to use Objective-C Cocoapods in a Swift Project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31884507), but it just failed...

Comment: @shallowThought I tried all solution from that SO post and just failed...

Comment: You did not mention the way described for "If your pod file uses use_frameworks! flag". Tripple check.