# How to display a complex fraction in Swift

Tags: swift

Currently creating an app which has to store fractions and then display them based on certain inputs.

However the fractions are complicated exam question style, for example:

2x^2 + 3

```
<hr />
```

3x^2 + 4

How can I display such a fraction as a string in swift?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29225779/how-to-use-subscript-and-superscript-in-swift

Comment: Since we are talking about Strings: Can you provide an example of input data and what kind of output you expect? -- Or do you want to render this beautifully?

Comment: Thank you Mr.Bista, that does help me, however my main issue here is displaying the numerator with a line below it and the denominator below that. Any ideas?

Comment: ctietze ideally the strings will be stored in a data base and then accessed when a user searches for their tag. The fraction will then be presented nicely as it would be presented in a maths exam paper

Comment: Neither Swift nor the Foundation frameworks provide any methods to render mathematical expressions. But there are 3rd party libraries such as https://github.com/kostub/iosMath. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44228429/using-iosmath-in-swift for how to use it from Swift.