# Image loading effect in swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swift3, loading

I created a social media app, and I would like to enhance the UX.
For that, I would like to create an animation when an image is loading.
I would like to produce the same effect that we can see on Facebook for example

[image]

We don't really see it (only on profile image pictures), and I don't even know how I could describe it (I'm not an English native). It's like a flash from the left to the right.

I have no idea about how I could do it. Someone has an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook actually has a handy library to help with this: https://github.com/facebook/Shimmer

From the github page's README, it's as simple as:

```
FBShimmeringView *shimmeringView = [[FBShimmeringView alloc] 
initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[self.view addSubview:shimmeringView];

UILabel *loadingLabel = [[UILabel alloc] 
initWithFrame:shimmeringView.bounds];
loadingLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
loadingLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Shimmer", nil);
shimmeringView.contentView = loadingLabel;

// Start shimmering.
shimmeringView.shimmering = YES;
```

The main thing you'd have to do is change the above code from using a `UILabel` to whatever `UIImageView` is being used for your profile images. Good luck!

Comment: Wow that's exactly what I'm looking for! But it seems to be in Objective-C, can I use it with Swift? (Sorry I'm new with swift dev)

Comment: Yes you can! Check out this other SO question/answer on that topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31884507/how-to-use-objective-c-cocoapods-in-a-swift-project -- should be as simple as adding any other Cocoapod as long as you have `use_frameworks!` in your Podfile

Comment: If I have more than 1 Objective-C pod, do I have to write every time I add an Objective-c pod?

Comment: No, it's a once per Podfile type of flag :)

Comment: The example of adding Shimmer to a label is in Objective-C, does anyone knows how to implement this code for swift 5?