# Pod Written in Obj C to Use in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Is there any possible way to use the pods which is coded in Obj C in Swift language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## You can directly use Objective c pod into your swift project

**Example:**

**Step 1.** Go to your project directory in your terminal and type `pod init`. This will create a pod file, edit the pod file by writing `pod 'Toast', '~> 4.0.0'`.

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'ObjcPOD' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
pod 'Toast', '~> 4.0.0'
  # Pods for ObjcPOD

end
```

**Step 2.** Run the command `pod install` in the terminal which will install pod into your project and thus generating .xcodeworkspace file. Open that file and then write:

```
import UIKit
import Toast

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.makeToast("Toast Here")
    }
}
```

Now you can run the app, done!

Answer (score 0):

Just use **use_frameworks!** flag in the podfile before giving pod name that you want to install like this:

```
   // Podfile
use_frameworks!
pod 'CoolObjectiveCLib'
```

for more detailed answer you can check @Vlad Papko answer here :
[How to use Objective-C Cocoapods in a Swift Project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31884507/how-to-use-objective-c-cocoapods-in-a-swift-project)

Comment: It's no longer required since `cocoapods 1.5.0`. Swift can use pods as static libs now.